# Test script if 'for' loops are correct without running code

Tags: python, pylint

I want to test, if the code is valid without running it.

So far I used pylint. It works, but if I have code like that

```
a = 1
for i in a:
    pass
```

it throw no error.

I need to test it with another code, like

```
from pylint import epylint as lint
(pylint_stdout, pylint_stderr) = lint.py_run('wrong.py',return_std=True)
```

Is there a way how to detect issues like that (maybe with different library)?

Comment: Python debugger (pycharm) does it for me without using libraries

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470/are-there-any-static-analysis-tools-for-python?rq=1

Comment: @PYPL I have seen that, but I have not found an answer there.